# Is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS compatible with Yocto Sumo 2.5.1?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, yocto, openembedded

I am relatively new to the Yocto project but do have some experience. Since the documentation on yoctoproject.org does not specifically list Ubuntu 18.04 as a "validated" release I switched to 16.04 version. I am now considering to switch back to 18.04 but will not do so if there is a known reasonable risk that yocto will produce errors. Please share your experience if you are using yocto sumo on ubuntu 18.04.

Thank you, Pavel.

Comment: I have been using every version of Yocto for the past 4 years and I don't recall having issues running a new version of Ubuntu than what's stated from Yocto's reference guide.

Comment: thank you I now feel comfortable to switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 works fine with latest revisions of Yocto 2.2 - 2.6.

Comment: Thank you, that tipped the scale in my decision.

Comment: What about Yocto version 2.7? Is it compatible with 18.04 Ubuntu.